# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed (Retrofit 2.1.0)

Tags: android, retrofit

When I try to invoke the Rest API, Throwing the below error in 
    `onFailure()` call back method

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

I'm using below libraries with Android Studio

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```

Comment: the url you're calling might not be signed with SSL certificate. I believe this is not your problem

Comment: please post code and also post your android manifest